# How to return all elements of a list before and including regex match?

Tags: regex, list, append, sublist

I want to split a list into various sub-lists. The list contains two types of elements: "colors" and a "color-IDs". The number of color-elements between the color-IDs varies:

```
colors = ['red', 'blue' ,'green', 'DocJ20031212doc1223', 'pink', 'yellow', 'DocNY20021212doc1212']
```

I want each sublist to contain all colors before the color-ID and the color-ID. I have tried to append the elements to a new list based on a regex, trying different indexes and if/if not combinations. After extensive research, this is the best I came up with:

```
colors_sorted = []

for i in colors:
    if re.search("Doc[a-zA-Z 0-9]{16}",i) or len(colors_sorted) == 0:
        colors_sorted.append([i])
    else:
        colors_sorted[-1].append(i)
print (colors_sorted)
```

However, this generates a new list that starts with the color-ID, while I want the color-ID to be the last element of each sub-list.

My output is:

```
[['red', 'blue', 'green'], ['DocJ20031212doc1223', 'pink', 'yellow'], ['DocNY20021212doc1212']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can rearrange your approach a little with a helper variable to store the sub-list:

```
colors_sorted = []
group = []
for i in colors:
    group.append(i)
    if i.startswith("Doc"):
        colors_sorted.append(group)
        group = []
```